# What's greater, enthalpy of combustion or heat of combustion?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the difference between the two? In my assignment book there is this question which asks if enthalpy of combustion is greater than, equal to or less than the heat of combustion. The answer given is that heat of combustion is greater and I don't understand why

Comment: Have they explained the difference between heat and enthalpy, particularly the condition that leads to them being equivalent? "Heat of combustion" is often used to mean "enthalpy of combustion", so I understand your confusion, but strictly speaking heat and enthalpy are different things, if sometimes equal.

Comment: In the question it's also mentioned that it's at constant volume. As far as my understanding goes, enthalpy is the total energy content and heat is basically transfer of energy. Since combustion is exothermic, energy is given to the surrounding but not all of the available energy of the substance is given. So in that case shouldn't the enthalpy of combustion be greater than heat of combustion ?

Answer (score 1):

The enthalpy of combustion (aka the heat of combustion) is the enthalpy change in going stoichiometrically from pure reactants to pure product at constant temperature and pressure.  The change in internal energy between these same two states is equal to $$\Delta U=\Delta H-\Delta(PV)=\Delta H-P\Delta V$$For a reaction in the ideal gas region, this reduces to $$\Delta U=\Delta H-\Delta(PV)=\Delta H-\Delta nRT\tag{1}$$Since the internal energy of an ideal gas is independent of volume, the pressure on the gases can be changed such that the volume of the products is the same as the volume of the reactants with no further change in internal energy.  So, for combustion of ideal gases, Eqn. 1 describes the relationship between the heat effect at constant volume and the heat of combustion at constant pressure.